# VPS Hosting with no OS?

Tags: vps, windows

Are there are any VPS hosts out there that don't come preconfigured for a particular OS?  I have my own Microsoft licensing and would profer not to pay a premium for redundant licensing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, no difference. You still want the OS from the hoster - it is preconfigured with all the stuff. What you dont want is to pay for it, and that is possible with the proper paperwork (to proove that you have he license). There is special licensing for the hoster in this case, this is well documented in the SPLA paperwork.

Comment: I had no idea they could do that.  Perfect!

Comment: It is pretty new, IIFC. That said, I was doing the same years ago when I was renting servers.

Comment: IIFC - that's a new acronym to me. What does it stand for?